# Abort thread properly when dialog box close button is clicked

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

Hello my fellow colleagues from StackOverflow!

I will try to be brief, so I will cut to the point:

I work on Windows XP, in C++, using pure Win32 to create a dialog box.

That dialog box has some edit controls, and OK button, which activates a thread when pressed.

Thread then gathers text from edit controls and writes them into MS Word document, using OLE Automation.

Everything works fine,when I press OK button, and wait for thread to show filled Word document.

**However, when I push the OK button and then close the dialog, while thread is in the middle of the work, a blank Word document pops up.**

To further illustrate my problem here are some code snippets:

This is snippet for thread function:

```
    DWORD WINAPI TabelaSvihObjekata( LPVOID hWnd ) // hWnd is handle of the Dialog box
    {

            // obtain dialogs window handle

        HWND hwnd = (HWND)hWnd;

        // Initialize COM for this thread...

        CoInitialize(NULL);

        // Get CLSID for our server...

        CLSID clsid;

        HRESULT hr = CLSIDFromProgID(L"Word.Application", &clsid);

            // do other Automation stuff and clean afterwards
    }
```

In dialog box, this is the snippet for button handler:

```
   case IDOK:
   {
        // create thread

        DWORD threadID;

        HANDLE threadHandle = CreateThread( NULL , 0 , 
                            (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)TabelaSvihObjekata , 
                            (void*)hwnd , 0 , &threadID );

        if( !threadHandle )
        {
           MessageBox( hwnd, L"Error", L"Error", MB_ICONERROR );

           EndDialog( hwnd, IDCANCEL );
        }

        CloseHandle( threadHandle );

   }
```

And this is the problematic handler:

```
    case IDCANCEL:

            EndDialog(hwnd, IDCANCEL);

        break;
```

I have looked on MSDN for a clue, and have found only ExitThread as a solution, but I don't know how to use it properly since I am inexperienced with threads.

Browsing through SO archive, I have found some examples in C# where people introduce boolean variable and test it's value in while loop, so they can determine whether to abort the thread or let it work.The other way was suggested, where thread is placed in separate process and then killed.

My question is:

**What should I add or change, so when I close the dialog box, Word application closes along with threads destruction ?**

If there is anything else that I can do to help, ask and I will gladly do it.

Thanks to everybody who tries to help.

Comment: this may be helpful: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/552/Using-Worker-Threads

Comment: It does give me some ideas, but it is mainly in MFC. I find it rather difficult to follow at this moment, since I am new to threads, but I will reread it again and again, hoping that it will help me to solve this problem.Thank you very much for the reply!

Comment: the main point I intended to convey was to use a boolean variable that is checked regularly inside your worker thread. If your main/gui thread needs the work to stop, it should set the boolean to false, and your worker should respond appropriately at it's next check in. Unfortunately, there is no automatic way to cleanup after a worker thread, so when your worker thread finds that (running == false), it should close ms-word if it has already opened, before returning from the thread function.

Comment: Good then,that is the way I understood it. So I just have to figure out how to implement the bool variable and the abort mechanism. Maybe like this : volatile bool SomeBool ? Should it be declared in dialog box ? If so, will my thread function be able to " see " it ? These are the problems that I am facing now. Again, thank you for the reply!

Comment: the volatile keyword makes it is safe to share the boolean between threads. I would put the boolean in the dialog box. For the worker thread to see it, you could pass a pointer to the boolean variable, or even the entire dialog box class, as the thread parameter. See the section "The Thread Solution" in the tutorial, where the poster passes a pointer to his CMyView class to his thread.

Comment: I don't have a dialog box class, since I use pure Win32. Maybe I could use structure to pass dialogs HWND and bool variable as fourth parameter to CreateThread ?

Comment: that would work too, just remember to store the struct somewhere it that it won't go out of scope after starting the thread =)

Comment: I will accept it and give you +1, I just have been confused by this answer I got here:http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/635139/Abort-thread-properly-when-dialog-box-close-button . It seems as they do not read the question, and now I am so confused that I can't pull myself together. I haven't forgotten about you, of that you can be sure!

Answer (score -2):

If you use WinApi you have to make threadhandle accesible by other part of code.
Then to terminate your thread you can use ExitThread - this is preferred option by MSDN. I show you how you can use it:

```
DWORD threadID;
HANDLE hthread;
void TerminateYourThread()
{
  DWORD exitCode;
  if(GetExitCodeThread(hThread,&exitCode) != 0) // check if your thread is active
  {
    ExitThread(exitCode); // terminating thread

    if(CloseHandle(hThread)) // closing handle
    {
       //
    }
  }
}

void CreateYourThread()
{
   hThread = CreateThread( NULL , 0 , 
                        (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)TabelaSvihObjekata , 
                        (void*)hwnd , 0 , &threadID );
}
```

Now when you want to terminate the thread just call TerminateYourThread function. It waits until thread is closed. **This is only suggestion not finally solution so you can refactor it in the future.**

Comment: OK, thank you! I will have to carefully study this snippet, since I am new to threads. We will " stay in touch ", since I will report my progress as soon as possible. Thanks again!

Comment: To clarify, ExitThread() will exit the CALLING thread. So why call GetExitCodeThread()? A thread does not need to check if itself is running =/ conversely, calling ExitThread from the main thread will not have the desired effect.